# ffmpeg an image sequence

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I want to encode a sequence of images to an video file, I have done this in the past with something like:

`ffmpeg -i %08d.jpg out.mp4`

But first I had to rename the files to be in that %08d.jpg format.  I want to just encode them and let them be in alphabetical order (or whatever) without having to rename them, is this possible?  I tried with using *.jpg and ffmpeg just hung and eventually crashed.

Comment: Not possible by default. `*.jpg` will simply expand to all filenames before FFmpeg even sees the asterisk. Why couldn't you just rename the files, if I may ask? Or copy them somewhere else, then rename? Maybe you can pipe the images into FFmpeg similar to `cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2 -i pipe: -r 25 out.mp4`?

Comment: You can do it with Symbolic Links to your list of files... Have a look at this link to give you an idea: [Sort images by aspect ratio](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50262/2343)

Comment: I do currently just rename the files, with a little python script, but it's a kludge and I thought it likely there was a more elegant solution I wasn't aware of.  The symbolic link thing had occurred to me, too, but it's really just as much work as renaming the files anyway.  I will try the pipe thing next...

Comment: Have you tried the pipe already? Would be interested to see if that works

Comment: No, it didn't work.  But on reading the man pages to try and figure out the syntax to make it work, I saw something else which solved the problem.  I'll post it as an answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually possible to let ffmpeg actually handle the glob for you. Use the [`-pattern_type` option](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#image2-2) from the `image2` demuxer and wrap the glob in single quotes to prevent expansion:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' out.mp4
```

For older versions of FFmpeg, you could use the `%` character, for example:

```
ffmpeg -i %*.jpg out.mp4
```

The above is however considered deprecated.

Comment: Wouldn't just `'*.jpg'` (note the apostrophes) work just as well, and be a little more familiar since it doesn't rely on a tool-specific syntax?

Comment: nope, and that doesn't work at all.  it's explained why in the man pages.

Comment: Be aware that the syntax you were using is considered deprecated and might be removed soon. I added the new syntax from the latest version of the FFmpeg manual but kept the old version as well.

Comment: [ffmpeg Error: Pattern type 'glob' was selected but globbing is not support ed by this libavformat build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31201164/395857): "glob is defined in the POSIX standard and it's not available on Windows by default."