# ffmpeg - Create a video from image frame with a start and a count

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Using `ffmpeg`, I made a video from multiple images with the below, which works, however I don't want to use all 200 images in my folder, wanting the video to contain only images from 1 to 100:

```
ffmpeg -start_number n -i test_%d.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 test.avi
```

How can I specify the number of frames to include in the video, or the number of the ending frame?

Comment: I don't know much about this program, but if it's using every image in a particular folder, why not create a new folder and only put in the 100 frames you want?

Comment: That be will my "hack solution" if can't do it with ffmpeg :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You do this by stating the number of frames you want with `-vframes 100`:

```
ffmpeg -start_number 1 -i test_%d.jpg -vframes 100 -vcodec mpeg4 test.avi
```

- You might need to specify other parameters such as `pix_fmt`, etc. depending on other factors, and usually one uses something like `test_%05d.jpg` with the numbered sequence having preceding zeroes with five digits; if you don't have it in that format you **might** need to use a [globbing pattern](https://superuser.com/questions/491590/ffmpeg-an-image-sequence).

Comment: good answer.
Note that the placement of vframes matters. You can't put it directly before your output parameter.

Answer (score 6):

This always works well for me:

```
ffmpeg -i yourfile.mp4 -r 1 -ss 15 -t 16 -f image2 snapshot.jpg
                                ^     ^ 
                                ^     ^
                              start  end
                               time   time
```

- `yourfile.mp4`: movie clip
- `snapshot.jpg`: new image file
- IMPORTANT: leave `image2` alone, as it was the only way to get what I wanted

Time is in seconds only; If it's 2 minutes ahead of the reel, then it's `120`.
One image file is always one-second worth, thus calculate your desired image by that approach.

Comment: I appreciate this command, because it works with old `ffmpeg` which I have to use right now; the only thing is `-t` is not "end time", `man ffmpeg` states it is "duration"; so end time would be start+duration. Cheers!

Comment: -to means end time.